# "Instance <Server at 0x2298c...> is not persisted"

Tags: pgadmin-4

After a fresh install of postgreSQL15, it seems as if it installed correctly, because I can access the server through psql just fine.

[image: psql running sucessfully]

But, when I attempt to access it through pgAdmin4, it does not automatically detect the server.

Because of this, I attempted to manually add the server through the "Register - Server" dialog box, but then I was prompted with this error: "Instance <Server at 0x2998c4c0af0> is not persisted".

[image: "Register - Server" Dialog Box Error]

I have tried to fully uninstall and reinstall both the entirety of postgreSQL15 as well as just pgAdmin4, without any luck.  I've tried to keep my settings to default to hopefully eliminate any issues, but it hasn't worked thus far.

I'm running this system on windows 10, not inside a docker container, just installed in the program files folder on my PC.

My main question is how to make my server "persist" so I can get some databases up and running.

- Reinstalling pgAdmin4 - Expected a persistent server so I can connect through pgAdmin4
- Reinstalling postgreSQL15 - Expected a persistent server so I can connect through pgAdmin4

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had the same issue.
I tried removing the data in the **C:\Users%USER%\AppData\Local\pgadmin** folder, and received the same error upon reinstalling.

I deleted the **pgadmin** folder within the **C:\Users%USER%\AppData\Roaming** folder, and deleted the **pgadmin** folder in **C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local**.
This fixes the problem for most users, however in some cases a re-installation may be needed as well.

Comment: I deleted the files you mentioned, uninstalled "entire application" using the postgre uninstall wizard, then reinstalled (again using the wizard).  It appears your solution worked!  Thank you!

Comment: I was able to solve it by simply closing PgAdmin4, deleting the two directories and restarting PgAdmin4. I did not have to reinstall anything.

Comment: just deleting stuff from the Roaming folder did it for me

Comment: It helped me too. Thank you. I removed recommended folders and installed again the pgAdmin.

Comment: Thanks, helped me too. Worked just by removing the directories, without reinstalling. Seems to have been caused by starting multiple incompatible versions of pgAdmin and thus corrupting its files.

Please correct the typos in the directory paths. The following worked for me:
`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming`
`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local`

Comment: just delete the files in the folders, not the folders themselves. And then reinstalling pgAdmin is not necessary.

Comment: This fixed it for me, after an update between PG4 versions.

Comment: An update of PGAdmin 4 versions also caused this and I was able to fix it by removing the files without reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

For mac, delete the following hidden folder created by `pgAdmin` at `/Users/<username>/.pgadmin` and restart pgAdmin4.